# Trying to convert waveform to mel-spectrogram using Pytorch and get an error

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network, spectrogram, torchaudio

So I want to prepare data to train the model by converting waveform array to mel-spectrogram

```
#Hyperparameters
hop=192               #hop size (window size = 6*hop)
sr=16000              #sampling rate
min_level_db=-100     #reference values to normalize data
ref_level_db=20
```

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from tqdm import tqdm
from functools import partial
import math
import heapq
from torchaudio.transforms import MelScale, Spectrogram

torch.set_default_tensor_type('torch.cuda.FloatTensor')

specobj = Spectrogram(n_fft=6*hop, win_length=6*hop, hop_length=hop, pad=0, power=2, normalized=True)
specfunc = specobj.forward
melobj = MelScale(n_mels=hop, sample_rate=sr, f_min=0.)
melfunc = melobj.forward

def melspecfunc(waveform):
  specgram = specfunc(waveform)
  mel_specgram = melfunc(specgram)
  return mel_specgram

def normalize(S):
  return np.clip((((S - min_level_db) / -min_level_db)*2.)-1., -1, 1)


def prep(wv,hop=192):
  S = np.array(torch.squeeze(melspecfunc(torch.Tensor(wv).view(1,-1))).detach().cpu())
  S = librosa.power_to_db(S)-ref_level_db
  return normalize(S)
```

```
#Waveform array from path of folder containing wav files
def audio_array(path):
  ls = glob(f'{path}/*.wav')
  adata = []
  for i in range(len(ls)):
    x, sr = tf.audio.decode_wav(tf.io.read_file(ls[i]), 1)
    x = np.array(x, dtype=np.float32)
    adata.append(x)
  return np.array(adata)

#Generate spectrograms from waveform array
def tospec(data):
  specs=np.empty(data.shape[0], dtype=object)
  for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    x = data[i]
    S=prep(x)
    S = np.array(S, dtype=np.float32)
    specs[i]=np.expand_dims(S, -1)
  print(specs.shape)
  return specs
```

```
awv = audio_array('../content/cmu_us_clb_arctic/wav')                               #get waveform array from folder containing wav files
aspec = tospec(awv)                                                                 #get spectrogram array
```

with provided code I get this error

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-8c9c4e76c626> in <cell line: 7>()
      5 #MALE1
      6 awv = audio_array('../content/cmu_us_clb_arctic/wav')                               #get waveform array from folder containing wav files
----> 7 aspec = tospec(awv)                                                                 #get spectrogram array
      8 adata = splitcut(aspec)                                                             #split spectrogams to fixed length
      9 #FEMALE1

<ipython-input-6-e2708ad61629> in tospec(data)
      6   for i in range(data.shape[0]):
      7     x = data[i]
----> 8     S=prep(x)
      9     S = np.array(S, dtype=np.float32)
     10     specs[i]=np.expand_dims(S, -1)

<ipython-input-5-84bbe915f261> in prep(wv, hop)
     79 
     80 def prep(wv,hop=192):
---> 81   S = np.array(torch.squeeze(melspecfunc(torch.Tensor(wv).view(1,-1))).detach().cpu())
     82   S = librosa.power_to_db(S)-ref_level_db
     83   return normalize(S)

<ipython-input-5-84bbe915f261> in melspecfunc(waveform)
     26 def melspecfunc(waveform):
     27   specgram = specfunc(waveform)
---> 28   mel_specgram = melfunc(specgram)
     29   return mel_specgram
     30 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torchaudio/transforms/_transforms.py in forward(self, specgram)
    410 
    411         # (..., time, freq) dot (freq, n_mels) -> (..., n_mels, time)
--> 412         mel_specgram = torch.matmul(specgram.transpose(-1, -2), self.fb).transpose(-1, -2)
    413 
    414         return mel_specgram

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (263x577 and 201x192)
```

I believe there is something wrong with torchaudio or hyperparameters.

First, I ran the notebook with sagemaker studio there is no problem about this but when I moved to Colab, it doesn't work anymore

The notebook in case you need it : https://github.com/marcoppasini/MelGAN-VC (Dataset included)

Comment: The tensors in your code need to be the same size to be multiplied.

specgram.transpose(-1, -2) and self.fb are not the same shape. Either the input data is in the wrong format or the code incorrectly manipulates the size of the tensors.